# Asp.net deployment issue

Tags: asp.net

we have two website which have the same assembly while compiling. the new changes has been deployed to test server with the same assembly name and it works fine. But in production one works and the other do not work, both are compile with the same assemble and has the same file as well? help me

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: thanks will do in future